# I am writing a script to transfer data entered into google sheets into a google doc

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to write a script to pull information from a google sheet in a formatted google doc. I had the script running before the google update. It will no longer run. The error I usually get is attempted to execute, but could not save. Also, illegal character line 18. I can not figure out how to fix it. I am somewhat new to all this and teaching myself along the way. Help is appreciated. The script is below.

```
function onOpen() {
const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
const menu = ui.createMenu('AutoFill Docs');
menu.addItem('Create New Docs', 'createNewGoogleDocs')
menu.addToUi();

}

function createNewGoogleDocs() {
const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1- 
TMh56SXOs6dWEsa1YWc5l9nbdTNn5pSIaCC23w-okc');
const destinationFolder = 
DriveApp.getFolderById('1K6U9327cBby96eXoX-YPVTpWRgznt7I1')
const sheet = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('TEST DOR 
62');
const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

rows.forEach(function(row, index){
if (index === 0) return;
if (row[50]) return;
const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[2]}, ${row[0]} 
Employee Details` , destinationFolder)
const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
const body = doc.getBody();
const friendlyDate = new Date(row[4]).toLocaleDateString();

body.replaceText('{{Q1}}', row[2]);
body.replaceText('{{Q2}}', row[3]);
body.replaceText('{{Q3}}', friendlyDate);
body.replaceText('{{Q4}}', row[5]);
body.replaceText('{{Q5}}', row[6]);
body.replaceText('{{Q6}}', row[7]);
body.replaceText('{{Q7}}', row[8]);
body.replaceText('{{Q8}}', row[9]);
body.replaceText('{{Q9}}', row[10]);
body.replaceText('{{Q10}}', row[11]);
body.replaceText('{{Q11}}', row[12]);
body.replaceText('{{Q12}}', row[13]);
body.replaceText('{{Q13}}', row[14]);
body.replaceText('{{Q14}}', row[15]);
body.replaceText('{{Q15}}', row[16]);
body.replaceText('{{Q16}}', row[17]);
body.replaceText('{{Q17}}', row[18]);
body.replaceText('{{Q18}}', row[19]);
body.replaceText('{{Q19}}', row[20]);
body.replaceText('{{Q20}}', row[21]);
body.replaceText('{{Q21}}', row[22]);
body.replaceText('{{Q22}}', row[23]);
body.replaceText('{{Q23}}', row[24]);
body.replaceText('{{Q24}}', row[25]);
body.replaceText('{{Q25}}', row[26]);
body.replaceText('{{Q26}}', row[27]);
body.replaceText('{{Q27}}', row[28]);
body.replaceText('{{Q28}}', row[29]);
body.replaceText('{{Q29}}', row[30]);
body.replaceText('{{Q30}}', row[31]);
body.replaceText('{{Q31}}', row[32]);
body.replaceText('{{Q32}}', row[33]);
body.replaceText('{{Q33}}', row[34]);
body.replaceText('{{Q34}}', row[35]);
body.replaceText('{{Q35}}', row[36]);
body.replaceText('{{Q36}}', row[37]);
body.replaceText('{{Q37}}', row[38]);
body.replaceText('{{Q38}}', row[39]);
body.replaceText('{{Q39}}', row[40]);
body.replaceText('{{Q40}}', row[41]);
body.replaceText('{{Q41}}', row[42]);
body.replaceText('{{Q42}}', row[43]);
body.replaceText('{{Q43}}', row[44]);
body.replaceText('{{Q44}}', row[45]);



doc.saveAndClose();
const url = doc.getUrl();
sheet.getRange(index + 1, 46).setValue(url)

})

}
```

Comment: check this line of code? const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[2]}, ${row[0]} 
Employee Details` , destinationFolder)

Comment: Did you try the suggested solution? Please provide feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I see at least two problems:

Bad formatting. The 'line 18' (the number depends on formatting as well) is broken. Probably it should be:

```
const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[2]}, ${row[0]} Employee Details`, destinationFolder);
```

And probably here:

```
doc.saveAndClose();
const url = doc.getUrl();
```

You close the doc and then you're trying to get its URL. It doesn't look right.

I'd propose to change the lines this way:

```
const url = doc.getUrl();
doc.saveAndClose();
```

Just in case, here is the code with fixed formatting. Try it:

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu('AutoFill Docs');
  menu.addItem('Create New Docs', 'createNewGoogleDocs')
  menu.addToUi();
}

function createNewGoogleDocs() {
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1-TMh56SXOs6dWEsa1YWc5l9nbdTNn5pSIaCC23w-okc');
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1K6U9327cBby96eXoX-YPVTpWRgznt7I1')
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('TEST DOR 62');
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  rows.forEach(function (row, index) {
    if (index === 0) return;
    if (row[50]) return;
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[2]}, ${row[0]} Employee Details`, destinationFolder)
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    const body = doc.getBody();
    const friendlyDate = new Date(row[4]).toLocaleDateString();

    body.replaceText('{{Q1}}', row[2]);
    body.replaceText('{{Q2}}', row[3]);
    body.replaceText('{{Q3}}', friendlyDate);

    // the loop instead of the 40 lines of code
    for (var i = 4; i < 45; i++) {
      body.replaceText('{{Q'+ i +'}}', row[i+1]);  
    }

    const url = doc.getUrl();
    doc.saveAndClose();
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 46).setValue(url)

  })
}
```

Comment: Not having the same error codes, but the script is still not running correctly. It will not pull information from the sheet and "replaceText" as it is supposed to.

Comment: If you share a sample of your sheet and doc I'm sure I can fix it. There can be another problems that have nothing to do with the code. The code works by itself with my dummy data.

Comment: I figured it out. Before the google update, I needed the double brackets {{Q3}}. I took a shot and removed a set of brackets and it now works. {Q3}. Annoying when it's something so simple.